# SQLAlchemy, MySQL, and python - how should I handle boolean?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a Pyramid application that I am using with SQLAlchemy and MySQL.  For database fields that I wanted to treat as boolean, I've been using a "BIT" data type on the SQLAlchemy side, and BIT(1) on the MySQL side.

This had all been working fine, but I was checking some newly updated code on my webhost and their version of phpMyAdmin is newer than the one I'm using locally; I was browsing a table that has a BIT field and on the newer phpMyAdmin none of the data appears - it's just blank.  On my local instance BIT fields display as 0 or 1.  If I tried to inline edit the hosted phpMyAdmin it wouldn't take any values I tried.  I did try my application code and it appears to be able to toggle the true/false values just fine.

The got me wondering - with this setup should I be approaching it differently? SQLAlchemy does support Boolean, which seems like it would be more intuitive and appropriate, should I use that and set the MySQL fields to TINYINT instead?

What is the conventionally accepted way to handle booleans between SQLAlchemy and MySQL?

Comment: MySQL actually has a `BOOLEAN` datatype, but it's an alias for `TINYINT(1)`.  You save nothing with `BIT(1)`, since it still requires a full byte for storage.  I'd definitely recommend going with SQLAlchemy Boolean and MySQL `TINYINT`.  If you want to enforce a constraint that the `TINYINT` only be `0` or `1`, you can do so by making it a foreign key into a `Booleans` table.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that, or maybe I aw the tinyint reference but didn't see the full-on BOOLEAN native type.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has a `BOOL` type (which is what SQLAlchemy uses) so I'm not sure why you don't just use that? Apparently [it is an alias](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) for `TINYINT`.

`from sqlalchemy import Boolean` and you should be good to go.